# How can I send a Base64 Image as a body in POST

Tags: java

I'm looking  to make a post request with a base64 image. When I make the request, I get an error called "ERROR_ZERO_CAPTCHA_FILESIZE" from the api. When I looked up what it means it says:
 Image size is less than 100 bytes. Check the image file, the post returns this error message:

```
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        File originalFile = new File("sec_token.php.png");
        String encodedBase64 = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStreamReader = new FileInputStream(originalFile);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)originalFile.length()];
            fileInputStreamReader.read(bytes);
            encodedBase64 = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(encodedBase64);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://2captcha.com/in.php?key=61f5d7a6cccc2db4e7c503a59f4f7e&method=base64&imginstructions="+encodedBase64).openConnection();

        String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0";
        System.out.println("User agent: " + USER_AGENT);
        //add request header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Host", "2captcha.com");

        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        String res = response.toString();
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot see where you send your request. You only setup a request header and fetch a reference to the output stream. But nothing is done with it afterwards.

Comment: @Heri clearly I send a request, so thats not a problem

Comment: @Deadpool  Its in the local directory

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at the API docs and it looks like you need to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` for the POST body.

```
    File originalFile = new File("sec_token.php.png");
    String encodedBase64 = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStreamReader = new FileInputStream(originalFile);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)originalFile.length()];
        fileInputStreamReader.read(bytes);
        encodedBase64 = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(encodedBase64);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://2captcha.com/in.php").openConnection();

    String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0";
    System.out.println("User agent: " + USER_AGENT);
    //add request header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Host", "2captcha.com");

    String data = "method=base64&body=" + encodedBase64 + "&key=[API_KEY]";
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeChars(data);
    wr.flush();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
        response.append(inputLine);
    }

    String res = response.toString();
    System.out.println(res);
```

Comment: Tried that and it didnt work, even if I paste the correct url into my browser I get the same error...

Comment: @IfaBoss You weren't using the API correctly. Updated.

Comment: Consider using the original API: https://github.com/2captcha/2captcha-api-examples/tree/master/ReCaptcha%20v2%20API%20Examples/Java%20Example

Comment: @devginalu This api is for a google ReCaptcha, I'm trying to solve a normal image captcha, The only info I could find was here: https://2captcha.com/2captcha-api#solving_normal_captcha

Comment: @devginalu  Your code returned Invalid user key. I changed a few things to fix that, but then it returned the same error. Here is the code with my real api key in it (if you want to test it more)  https://pastebin.com/hAJ3KqJ7

Comment: @devginalu,  here is the base64 string that my code generates:
https://pastebin.com/mFaV7Wi0